# Avoiding allOf swagger syntax generated by swagger-core

Tags: swagger-2.0

I'm using a generator based on *io.swagger*'s *swagger-core* + *swagger-jaxrs* library *v1.5.13* and I wonder if there's an option to **avoid** `allOf` syntax. The other tool we use doesn't support the `allOf` syntax and we can't use it.

I don't like bending our java model just because of one problematic technology, is there and option how to tell the library not to generate `allOf` and **flatten the view on a hirarchy of objects** instead?

I already have a custom `ModelResolver`, but I hope for a more elegant solution than transforming the syntax with my code.